# Prove that if $~\sum a_n=A~$ , $~\sum b_n=B~$ , and $~\sum c_n=C$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ be sequences. Define $\displaystyle c_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n+1-k}$.

Prove that if $~\sum a_n=A~$ , $~\sum b_n=B~$ , and $~\sum c_n=C~$ (so they are all convergent series) then $C=AB$. (Note that we do *not* need $\sum a_n$ to be absolutely convergent).

Hello everyone. I am stuck on how to start this problem. I don't want the answer, just a hint on how to get started.

Comment: Hint: What is the general term in the product of sequences $(\sum a_{n})(\sum b_{n})$?

Comment: @MartinR I looked at the question you reference. I have to admit that the answer is not obvious to read on my side... Yes it implies that $A(x)B=C(x)$ for $0\lt x \lt 1$ where $C(x)$ is the Cauchy product of $A(x)$ and $B$. Yes also $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} C(x)$ exists as $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} A(x)=A$. What I don't see is why $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} C(x)=C$? Which is in fact the question raised.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: That follows from [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), as I understand it. The convergence of $C= \sum c_n$ implies that $\lim_{x \to 1_-} C(x) = C$. The same applies to the other two series.

Comment: It is clear that $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} A(x)=A$ is a consequence of [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). But $C(x)$ has a form that is not the one of Abel's theorem, i.e. something like $\sum_n c_n x^n$. It is $\sum_n (\sum_k a_k b_{n-k} x^k)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I think it has. With $A(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ and $B(x) = \sum  b_n x^n$ you have $A(x)B(x) = C(x)$ for $|x| < 1$, where $C(x) = \sum c_n x^n$ and  $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$. (I'm using zero-based indices for convenience.) This is the Cauchy product of power series. Then $x \to 1-$ and Abel's theorem gives $AB = C$. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I was only thinking of Cauchy product for series and not power series. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, the teacher has not taught us about Merten's theorem or Abel's theorem so I am not allowed to use those.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I misunderstood the question previously. What you are looking for is probably [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771606/551240) , which says :

> Let $\sum a_{n}~$ ,  $\sum b_{n}$  are conditionally convergent complex series,   $\sum c_{n}$ is the Cauchy product of $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ such that $\sum c_n$ converges. Then, $$\sum c_{n} = \left(\sum a_{n}\right)\left(\sum b_{n}\right)$$

For a complete proof, please refer to [same link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771606/551240) as above.

---

**EDIT :** Updated the links. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: This is not an answer to the posted question. Merten's theorem supposes that one of the series is absolutely convergent. This is explicitly mentioned by the OP as **not being the case.**

Comment: If none of the two series absolutely converges, then is the result necessarily true ?

Comment: Yes, because it is *assumed* in the question that $\sum c_n$ is convergent. See the possible duplicate target pointed out at the question.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Your links still point to the standard version of Mertens' theorem and its proof, which requires that one of the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to update the links. Can you please check now ?