# Prove that if $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ and $\sum c_n$ converge to A,B and C then $C=AB$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define $\displaystyle c_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n+1-k}$. Prove that if $\sum a_n=A$, $\sum b_n=B$ and $\sum c_n=C$ then $C=AB$.

My teacher did not teach us Merten's Theorem or Abel's theorem. Is there a way to prove this without those theorems?

I don't know if this is the right approach, but I tried multiplying $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ and got

$$\sum a_n \sum b_n=a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+b_0a_1)+...+(a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}b_1+a_nb_0)$$

I think this is ultimately my goal:
$$(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n)(\sum_{n=1}^N b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Na_n\cdot b_k=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cdot b_{n-k+1}$$

but I dont know how to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Na_n\cdot b_k=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cdot b_{n-k+1}$$

Comment: The terms that you calculated are precisely the $c_n$s (Cauchy product of $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ ).

Comment: I was told that $\sum c_n$ being convergent was enough to prove that statement and that $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ do not have to be absolutely convergent.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938212).

Comment: Yes - if all three converge then $AB=C$

Answer (score 2):

You can show that $\sum_n c_n$ is Cesaro-summable to $AB$, provided that $\sum_n a_n = A$, and $\sum_n b_n = B$ ([Cesàro's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Ces%C3%A0ro%27s_theorem)). If $\sum_n c_n$ is also summable, it must have sum $AB$.